# How to create linq query using namespace using ... syntax

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

I'm confused as to how namespaces work.  I'm trying to get the `worksheet` where `ss:Name="Datagrid"` and from that get the `data` node where `name="emailname"`

```
Imports <xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
Module Module1   
    Sub Main()
        Dim xmlFile As String = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory & "Datagrid.xml"
        Dim root As XElement = XElement.Load(xmlFile)

    ''select worksheet where ss:Name="Datagrid""
    'Dim dg = From item In root .......................

    ''get data from wokrsheet...table..row...data where = name="emailname"  (not ss:name="emailname")

    'Dim data = From item In dg .......................
    End Sub
End Module
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Datagrid">
    <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="13" ss:ExpandedRowCount="11" x:FullColumns="1"
     x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
      <Row ss:Index="3" ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell Name="emailname">
          <Data ss:Type="String">email address</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row ss:Index="4" ss:AutoFitHeight="0">
        <Cell Name="username">
          <Data ss:Type="String">user name</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
  <Worksheet ss:Name="Properties">
    <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="3" x:FullColumns="1"
     x:FullRows="1" ss:DefaultRowHeight="15">
      <Row>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="Number">1</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="Number">2</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell>
          <Data ss:Type="Number">3</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the namespaces with `Imports` statements at the top of the file. Then you can refer to them with the `<ns:name>` syntax.

So

```
Imports <xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
Imports <xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
Imports <xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
Imports <xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
Imports <xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

will give you the namespaces defined by the XML you've provided.

Now you could access `<Workbook>...<Table>.@x:FullRows` including in LINQ queries.

These XML features of VB.NET are referred to as [Axis Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384769.aspx) in the Microsoft documentation.

I've pasted your XML into VS2008 and determined your issue is that the XML tags, including in Axis Properties, are case *sensitive*:

```vb
''select worksheet where ss:Name="Datagrid""
'Dim dg = From item In root .......................
Dim dg = root.<Worksheet>.FirstOrDefault(Function(w) w.@ss:Name = "Datagrid")

If dg Is Nothing Then _
    Throw New Exception("DataGrid not found")

''get data from wokrsheet...table..row...data where = name="emailname"  (not ss:name="emailname")

'Dim data = From item In dg .......................
' Both of the following lines work, but the second answers the question in the title:
'Dim data = dg.<Table>.<Row>.<Cell>.FirstOrDefault(Function(d) d.@Name = "emailname")
Dim data = dg...<Cell>.FirstOrDefault(Function(d) d.@Name = "emailname")

If data Is Nothing Then _
    Throw New Exception("emailname not found")

Console.WriteLine(data.<Data>.Value)
```

Comment: Hey, you're already using this syntax "`item.@ss:Name`"! So have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: I think so, I'm trying  to get the datagrid whose ss:Name="Datagrid" and from that get the <data> node whose name="data" (not ss:name="data")

Comment: Note the default namespace (`xmlns`) is the same as `xmlns:ss`, so `name` and `ss:name` is the same.

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit In case you didn't notice my edit, I believe you were on the right track, except you needed to get the case of `Name` correct.

Answer (score 0):

To get a cleaner syntax, suggest trying the Linq-to-XML XPath extension method shown below.

Update #1: The below code works if the XML file doesn't contain any namespaces. Working on a solution to consider namespaces.

```
Dim root = XElement.Load(xmlFile)
Dim data = root.XPathSelectElements("Worksheet[@Name=""Datagrid""]/Table/Row/Cell/Data[@Name=""edata""]")
```